# iOS 9 and Siri's Smart Reminders

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, siri

I'm in a little bit of trouble with supporting Siri's Smart Reminders. It's using NSUserActivity() in order to creating a contextual reminder.

Try it with Safari and Messages : say "Remind me about this". A reminder will be created with the title of the webpage / the message as the title of the reminder, and a deep link to Safari/Messages.

Back to my issue. I can create a contextual reminder with the title only… Without even touching my code (thanks to Handoff). But I can't add a deep link to my app like Safari or Messages…

Here's my code (Swift) :

```
let webHandoff: NSUserActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "com.jpierna.Trophies")
        webHandoff.webpageURL = NSURL(string: BaseURL + "/game.php?id=\(detail.id)")
        webHandoff.title = detail.title

        self.userActivity = webHandoff
        self.userActivity?.becomeCurrent()
```

Siri use webHandoff.title to give the reminder a title. At first I expected Siri to give my webpageURL to the reminder, but nothing. Then I searched if I could add deep linking between the reminder and my app (e.g. the reminder opens my app with the same data, like url schemes, no issues with that), but nothing too.

Apple documentation talks mainly about Spotlight Proactive Search and Core Spotlight, but not really about Siri's Smart Reminders.

Maybe could somone show me how to properly add this in my app ?

Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double-check the values under the `NSUserActivityTypes` key in your `Info.plist` file. I've found that if your `activityType` value isn't declared there, Siri's "remind me about this"/"remember this" smart reminder will only get the title in your `NSUserActivity`, but no deep-linking app icon will appear.

Comment: It works, thanks !! The correct method in my AppDelegate now is application:continueUserActivity right ? :)

Comment: Yes, and also look at `-application:willContinueUserActivityWithType:`